# Text display inside an input text field

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

Need help displaying tail end portion of the entered text rather than start of the text inside an input text field.

Sample string entered could be "Starting portion, Ending Portion". Depending on the length of the input field(assuming length is set to 14 chars), instead of displaying first 14 characters in the visible area of text input, it should display last 14 characters of the string -> " Ending Portion

Comment: Please check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=angular+truncate+text+input+field+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score -1):

```
TextEditingContoller textFieldController = TextEditingContoller(text: "this text will be inside text field when build");
```

Dont forget make the text field as below

```
TextField(controller: textFieldController);
```

Comment: <input type="text" /> will be the HTML side - Not sure how i could use above with my angular appln...May be i am missing something?